# IPSD, IISD, MPP1+ and MSI scores

Tags: medications, cancer

First of all, sorry if this is not the correct Stack.

I am translating a clinical protocol for an antibody that could be used against certain types of cancer. I found the following and I have no idea what the acronyms mean:

```
Local Regression Analysis (e.g., **IPSD**, **IISD**, **MPP1**+ and **MSI** scores).
```

The document is confidential, so I cannot share a lot of information. I have found different meanings such as inhibitory postsynaptic density (iPSD) or membrane protein (MPP); however, none of them seem to make sense with "score". I have no idea where else to search for this information.

If it helps, the section of the document where I found the acronyms talks about the analysis of data after testing specimens with a specific antibody.

Thanks in advance if somebody has any information! :)

Comment: Is the paper in English? Doesn't seem like enough information to determine. Are the acronyms used anywhere else? A good reminder of why one should always define acronyms at their first use. Possibly they are genes but the phrasing here seems very unnatural if so.

Comment: Yes, it is in English. Sorry for not clarifying it. And no, the acronyms are not used nor defined anywhere else in the document or any other document from the same company in any other language. I really have no idea what they mean nor where can I find further context.  :(

Comment: Okay, I think then the question is probably not suitable here. StackExchange is meant to build a repository of useful Q&A for other visitors, and I can't see much use to anyone else in a translation of a specific document that's confidential and can't be shared for context. You could ask whoever provided you the document for clarification.

Comment: Ok! I have asked but haven't gotten a response. I thought that since this could be something people familiar with clinical research/cancer research could know and was using all the resources available :(. Thanks, tho!

Comment: Voting to close since the document is confidential and can't be shared, which makes the question impossible to answer.